# How to configure visual studio to ask to commit the code after a successful build?

Tags: visual-studio, mercurial, batch-file

Since it's the best practice to commit early, commit often I would like to be promoted with a dialog that will ask for a commit message and will commit to my local mercurial repository that I am working on.
What's the easiest way to implement such a feature?
I would like to avoid writing am add-in if possible.
One idea I had is to run a post build command that will execute a batch file.
In turn the batch file will check if the build was successful and then it will execute:

```
hg addremove
```

If nothing was either added or removed, no commit message will be requested. If any files were added or removed it will ask me for a commit message, once the commit message has been inputted it will execute:

```
hg commit -m "Insert message here"
```

Is it possible? If so, how?

Comment: This is an anti-pattern. Commits should be atomic units of work. Otherwise you get leakage from unrelated changes creeping in to a changeset, and it screws up the whole possibility of cherry picking changesets (or at least makes it much more difficult). It's a silly idea. Don't take the Commit Early Commit Often best practice so literally :)

Comment: @NathanE: The thing is that I really want to remind everyone to commit when they should. We're currently use subversion and most of the teams don't use branches so they don't commit until they are really done.

Comment: I suspect that'll probably just become "they don't push to master until they are really done". Once they see the benefits of DVCS, you'll probably have a hard time persuading them to do anything else. But forcing them to commit after every build will only put them off, and litter your history with nonsensical changesets. If you can swing some training time, or persuade them to use it for personal projects, **show them** how liberating it is to have hg watching over their code.

Comment: @shambulator: I am only concerned because most of the programmers at my company are inexperienced. Do you have any other suggestion for how might I enfore the workfolw?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I doubt you really want to do that.

Most patterns related to version control dictates that you want to know what the change was about. I build many times during the implementation of a single bug-fix, but your question leads me to think that you would think it was OK to get N commits, most of them bad, into your version control system, with no real purpose.

Now, I agree that it is best practice to commit early, and commit often, but it is not a best practice to commit blindly and commit just because it builds. You should commit when you got something you want to preserve.

Having said that, have you tried executing the `hg commit` command without any arguments whatsoever? The default behavior is to pop up a text file for editing, typically through your default text editor, and wait for you to save it with new content.

In other words, this should do what you want:

```
hg commit --addremove
```

However, and I strongly urge you to rethink this, you might question this decision at some point when you see a version history full of commits that are just endlessly editing files back and forth during some experimental development or bugfixing.

There's some good add-ins for Visual Studio out there as well, you might want to consider these instead:

- [VisualHG](http://visualhg.codeplex.com/)
- [HgSCC](http://www.newsupaplex.pp.ru/hgscc_news_eng.html)

Comment: I can choose to close the batch or add a conditional (y/n) prompt string if I don't want to commit I just want to force myself and others to commit to their local repository as soon as possible.

Comment: And I'm just going to reiterate that that is a bad idea. You are, in my opinion, basically trying to monkeypatch one bad workflow with another.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: So how do I enforce the Commit early, commit often policy for myself and for the other developers in the my company?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: Currently, it cannot be done. Any other suggestion?

Comment: No, sorry, if you don't trust your developers then I can't help you.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: Most of the developers in my company are new to programming (0-2 years of experience) and they don't know how to use source control that wat either. I figured that if the IDE would enforce the workflow for them, it might be easier for them to understand how to work better without these automations.

Comment: Well, did you try the `hg commit --addremove` thingy? It should pop open a textfile, if you don't save a message in it, it'll abort the commit. If you save a message in it, that's the commit message. You can execute that on post-build event, however, you need to execute it on the post-build event of *a project*, which might make it unsuitable for your use. You would have to make sure it's the last project built.

Comment: @the_drow: What do you mean, isn't that exactly what you asked for? Or did you perhaps mean a more dialog-y window, not just a notepad (or similar) window? If so, then you could actually build that yourself, you would have to create something that would edit a text file, accept a filename as an argument, and ask Mercurial to use that editor instead. I don't think it would take much work to make it.